# Running an eclipse job

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, job-scheduling

I am working on an RCP application, I have a use case in which I check if the root component is not null which means the model is already loaded and if it is null then the model is not loaded, if the model is not loaded then I try to load the model first in a separate job and then get the model once it is loaded. What I have written is

```
 if (cm != null) {
        LoadModel m = null;
        swaModel = architectureModelReader.getArchitectureModel();  
        Component rootComponent = swaModel.getRootComponent();
        if(rootComponent != null){
            MirrorConfigurationModel mcm = new MirrorConfigurationModel(rootComponent, connectionString, emptyEapName, platformDB.getAbsolutePath(),temp, getJetPath(), disabledComponents, disabledDiagrams, disabledInterfaces, disabledElements);
            mcm.execute();
        }
        else{
            final Job readArchitectureModelJob = new Job("Long Running Job") {
                protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                   try {
                      architectureModelReader.createSamInstance(monitor, true);
                      return Status.OK_STATUS;
                   }catch(final Exception e) {
                    return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
                }   
                }
             };
             readArchitectureModelJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
                public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                    if (event.getResult().isOK()){
                        Component c = swaModel.getRootComponent();
                        System.out.println(c.getName());
                    }
                   else
                        System.out.println("Job did not complete successfully");
                }
             });
             readArchitectureModelJob.setSystem(true);
             readArchitectureModelJob.schedule();
        }               
        }   

    }
```

So here if the root component is not null mirror the loaded model (which works fine) but if the root component is null I try to load the model in else clause and then getting the model but the problem is before the model is loaded in the else clause the handler jumps to

Can anyone tell me how to run this model loading job before I get the model?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to wait until the job has run and do whatever you want to do then.

Comment: How can I wait for the job to run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to delay what you want to do until the Job has run.

One way to this is to use an `IJobChangeListener` to listen for the job change events. Use:

```
job.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
      // TODO do your end of job processing here
    }
  });
```

to add the listener. Do this **before** the job is scheduled.

Comment: when I call m.execute() it should schedule and run the job and once teh job is completed shouldn't it run the code after else?

Comment: No, the job runs in a background thread and will finish much later. The schedule call returns as soon as the job has been added to the list of background jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... Done :)